# Problems with converting a CGPoint to a string

Tags: cocoa-touch, string, nsstring, cgpoint

I have been having problems with converting a CGPoint to a string.  I have tried various methods, but this seems like the most promising but it still won't work.  Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    coord = [touch locationInView:touch.view];  
    viewcoord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"coordinates %@", coord.x, coord.y];
```

I get output but it just says "coordinates (null)" and I don't understand why...

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

```
viewcoord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"coordinates %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(coord)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format string uses a `%@` which only applies to objective-C objects. You look like you're trying to print not one but two values (the x and the y), both of which are floats. Try this:

```
viewcoord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"coordinates %f, %f", coord.x, coord.y];
```